# Stored procedures for neo4j in clojure

Tags: clojure, neo4j, jvm, procedures

I have a question about stored procedures in Neo4j. I already succesfully wrote a few procedures in Java and got them working with Neo4j 3.0.1. However I would like to try to write a procedure in other JVM laguage-Clojure. As I am not so familiar with this language I would like to know, if any of you had tried to do something similar? Is it even possible?

I have also researched the possibility to call a clojure program from java, but have not jet been successful.